# Django Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): / POST / HTTP/1.1" 403 2864 on Google Colab

Tags: python, django, google-colaboratory

so i'm tryin to run my Django web program on **Google collab** based on this tutorial https://medium.com/@arsindoliya/running-django-on-google-colab-ea9392cdee86

And i did it the web can running!
[running web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NP7Gx.jpg)

But, if i want to make `POST` it's always error like this

> Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /
> [22/Feb/2022 02:13:47] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 403 2864

And i'm already try some solution like put the **CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True** inside my settings.py but still not working and i do put the `@csrf_token` on my form too and it's still not working.

Also i wanna try this solution to

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
```

but i'm still don't understand how to use that.

Does anyone has a solution for it? I'm still new in Django and i made it for my college's final project, so any solution that you guys make really helpful for me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

2 ways to solve this problem.

1. comment out the code about MIDDLEWARE in settings.py like this：

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    # 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

2. use @csrf_exempt to handle it,like this:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt


@csrf_exempt
def rule_api(request):

    pass
```

Comment: sorry, where can i put the number 2 handle? is it inside app urls, project urls or views?

Comment: in views.py,Place it above your logic function

Comment: im already try it but it only shows not implemented after post it

Comment: Show me your code and error message.

Answer (score 0):

In Django you useing method post you should do add it:

```
{% csrf_token %}
```

you can refer if at:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/csrf/

Comment: I'm already use it, but nothing happened

Comment: you can for me see it @lukasyahya_